# DOMDocument remove listeners from tags

Tags: php, domdocument

I'm using the DOMDocument with an HTML that uses Framework/Lib and has an event listener, but just ignores the attributes that have "AT=@":

```
$html = '<button @click="test()">ÁÈ</button>';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="utf-8" ?>' . $html);
dump($dom);

// Expected to happen - <button @click="test()">ÁÈ</button>
// Actually resulted  - <button>ÁÈ</button>
```

Note that `@click="test()"` was removed from string because of DOMDocument.

Comment: what voodoo is `@click` in the above HTML? Is that from some sort of framework as it's not valid HTML

Comment: Yes. I am using AlpineJS, but I did a trick giving str_replace for all ```@```.

Comment: @AndréRodrigues So is it done?

Comment: If you remove `libxml_use_internal_errors(true);` you get `error parsing attribute name`, which clearly shows that `@` is not allowed.

Comment: @nice_dev Yes, but I don't know if it's the right way to do it hahaha

Comment: @AndréRodrigues I would rather suggest a preg_replace to keep other valid `@` intact.

Comment: @nice_dev I could, but how I would save the name of listener?

Example: ```preg_replace('/@[A-z]+="/', 'at_event_listener', '<a @teste="aa" href="mailto:email@provider.com.br">Email</a>')```.

How would I get back the name of listener?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove all the event listeners that have `@` prefixed to them and to do so, you can use [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) for the same. Get the name of the event listener back while replacing with the help of regex group number.

```
<?php

$html = '<button @click="test()">ÁÈ</button>';

$html = preg_replace('/@([a-z]+)\=/i', '$1=', $html);

echo $html;

// rest of your code 

/*

$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="utf-8" ?>' . $html);

*/
```

[**Live Demo**](https://3v4l.org/eBfVs)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just increment a prefix before ```$1=```, like:  ```'tmp_at_event_listener_$1='```. So I can find where to switch back to the ```@``` event listener.

Comment: @AndréRodrigues Sure, you are free to pick and tweak things around once the solution is in place.

Comment: Taking advantage of the doubt, I was thinking about performance and I think it doesn't make sense for me to put it in a DOMDocument, do a foreach for this preg_replace, would I be able to use preg_replace in the string that already contains my HTML? Example attach the src from all img tag?

Comment: @AndréRodrigues Can you edit your post and give an example? It's difficult for me to comprehend as of now.